# Tz’ror ba-Kessef and Ikkurei Dinnim

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, responsa

[This article](https://hakirah.org/Vol28Broyde.pdf), footnote 40, refers to two responsa, neither of which I can track down:

- Tz’ror ba-Kessef YD 18 (there is a Tz’ror ha-Kessef, which may be what is meant, but if so I’ve been unable to find a legible copy of it online, so any help there would be much appreciated!)
- Ikkurei Dinnim 1, OC 40 (I can’t find anything beyond OC 36 in any of the editions I’ve looked in)

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The source for a Tzror HaKessef YD 18 is [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45621&st=&pgnum=73&hilite=) which seems to fall in line with the subject matter.

Comment: On the Otzar website there are editions of Ikkarei Dinim-Ikkarei Dat with OC 40 but you need to pay to see that far.